# Getting "SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]" with simple code sample

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm working through exercises in "Eclipse 4 Plug-in Development by Example Beginner's Guide".  I got to the section titled "Time for action – adding items to the tray" and I started to see errors like this when I ran my test instance:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: Not implemented [multiple displays]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4308)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDisplay(Display.java:760)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:896)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:157)
```

I've been reading some references about this error message, but I'm still not sure what I can do about it.

The changes specified in the exercise make calls to "Display.getDefault()", in both the "start" and "stop" methods of the "Activator" class, which extends AbstractUIPlugin.  I verified that commenting out those new changes removes the error.  I also tried a simple change of storing "Display.getDefault()" as an instance var and reusing that, instead of calling "Display.getDefault()" each time in "start" and "stop".  That didn't have any effect (and I have no idea whether that's a good idea or not).

This is the current state of the class, with some older blocks commented out:

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {
    private TrayItem    trayItem;
    private Image       image;
    private Display     display;

    public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "com.packtpub.e4.clock.ui"; //$NON-NLS-1$

    private static Activator plugin;

    public void setDisplay(Display display) {this.display = display;}
    public Display getDisplay() {return display;}

    public Activator() {}

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        super.start(context);
        plugin = this;

//      final Display   display = Display.getDefault();
        setDisplay(Display.getDefault());
        getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                image = new Image(getDisplay(), Activator.class
                        .getResourceAsStream("/icons/sample.gif"));
                Tray    tray    = getDisplay().getSystemTray();
                if (tray != null && image != null) {
                    trayItem    = new TrayItem(tray, SWT.NONE);
                    trayItem.setToolTipText("Hello World");
                    trayItem.setVisible(true);
                    trayItem.setText("Hello World");
//                  trayItem.setImage(new Image(trayItem.getDisplay(),
//                          Activator.class.getResourceAsStream("/icons/sample.gif")));
                    trayItem.setImage(image);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        if (trayItem != null && !trayItem.isDisposed()) {
//          Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (trayItem != null && !trayItem.isDisposed())
                        trayItem.dispose();
                }
            });
        }
        if (image != null && !image.isDisposed()) {
//          Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (image != null && !image.isDisposed())
                        image.dispose();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static Activator getDefault() {return plugin;}

    public static ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(String path) {
        return imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, path);
    }
}
```

**Update**:

As it appears this happens when more than one "Display" object is attempting to be created, I set a breakpoint in the two constructors in the Display class.

I hit the breakpoint as a result of calling "Display.getDefault()" in my Activator class, but I also hit it later, after my "start" method completed, with the following stack:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 500 in Display))   
    Display.<init>(DeviceData) line: 500    
    Workbench.createDisplay() line: 714 
    PlatformUI.createDisplay() line: 161    
    IDEApplication.createDisplay() line: 153    
    IDEApplication.start(IApplicationContext) line: 95  
    EclipseAppHandle.run(Object) line: 196  
    EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Object) line: 110 
    EclipseAppLauncher.start(Object) line: 79   
    EclipseStarter.run(Object) line: 344    
    EclipseStarter.run(String[], Runnable) line: 179    
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
    NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 57  
    DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: 43  
    Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 606  
    Main.invokeFramework(String[], URL[]) line: 622 
    Main.basicRun(String[]) line: 577   
    Main.run(String[]) line: 1410   
    Main.main(String[]) line: 1386
```

When I resume from this breakpoint, I see the "multiple displays" error.  So, the error doesn't happen in my class, it happens later, when another Display is being created.

**Update**:

As I continued through the exercises in this book, I ran into another block of code calling "Display.getDefault()", inside the "createPartControl()" method of a custom view.  I wondered what would happen here.  With my existing breakpoint in the two Display constructors, along with one in "getDefault()", and commenting out the problematic code in my "Activator" class, what I saw on startup of the test instance was that the first call to the Display constructor was in that stacktrace just before this, from "IDEApplication.createDisplay()".  After that, it got into my view creation, but the call to "Display.getDefault()" didn't create a new Display, because it already existed.

From what I've seen so far, it seems like it's not a good idea to put code in a bundle activator class that calls "Display.getDefault()", because when the IDEApplication fully starts up, it's going to force the creation of a Display, which will fail.

Comment: How is the plugin setup to run the Activator `start` method? This doesn't normally run until something else in the plugin executes. It looks like the plugin is running too soon before Eclipse has created the single Display.

Comment: The only reference to this "Activator" class that I can find outside of the class itself is in the MANIFEST.MF file, as the value of the "Bundle-Activator" property.

Comment: When I set a breakpoint in "start", it's called from "BundleContextImpl", if that helps.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this? I also faced similar.